# React-Redux | Productlist | Add/Remove w/ BindActionCreator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to create an product list in React where I can add and remove products.

I started to do some research on how I could do this using the [redux](https://redux.js.org/) framework/platform and react native

I already have an function `productList` container, `product` component and `cartList`, `cartProduct` component.

**My problems are:**

Products: I can only add products and not remove

Cart: Vice versa + the cart does not get updated on the status of the cart items.

I've added bindActionCreator but don't know how to apply it to my productList yet.

**What do I expect to happen?**
I'm trying to add and remove products from the react store in the same container/component.

How can I do this? Is my approach correct or am I completely wrong ?

A thank you in advance.

**ProductActionCreators**

```
export const ADD_TO_CART = 'ADD_TO_CART'
export const REMOVE_FROM_CART = 'REMOVE_FROM_CART'

export function addItemToCart(row) {
    return {
        type:'ADD_TO_CART', 
        payload: row, qty
    }
  }

  export function removeTodo(row) {
    return {
        type:'REMOVE_FROM_CART' , 
        payload: row, qty
    }
  }
```

**ProductList(simplified)**

```
     import React from 'react';
     import { Component } from 'react';
      import { 
        View,  
        StyleSheet, 
        Text
     } from 'react-native';
     import Products from '../components/Products';
     import { bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
     import { connect } from 'react-redux';

     import * as ProductActionCreators from '../actions/ProductActionCreators'

     export  class ProductList extends React.Component {
        static navigationOptions = {
            header: null,
        };
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            const { rows } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
            const arrays = Object.values( {rows});
            this.state = {
                arrays,
                filteredProducts: arrays,
            };
            const { dispatch } = props
            this.boundActionCreators = bindActionCreators(ProductActionCreators, dispatch)
            console.log(this.boundActionCreators)
        }



          render() {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container} >
                <Text style={styles.title} >
                    {this.state.arrays[0].name}
                </Text>
                    <Products products={this.state.arrays[0].data} onPress=
//Trying to change this to multiple actions
{this.props.addItemToCart}/>    
                </View>
            )
          }
        }

    const qty = 0;

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
        //need to add BindActionCreator
        return{
            addItemToCart:(row) => dispatch({
                type:'ADD_TO_CART', payload: row, qty

            }),
            removeItem:(product) => dispatch ({
                type:'REMOVE_FROM_CART' , payload: product, qty
            })  
        }

    }

    export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps) (ProductList);
```

**Product(simplified)**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    TextInput,
    FlatList,
} from "react-native";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";

class Products extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const { products } = this.props;
        this.state = {
            products, 
            filteredProducts: products,
        };
    }
    renderProducts = (products) => {
            return (
                <View key={products.index}>
                    <View> 
                        <Icon name={products.item.icon} color="#DD016B" size={25} />
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <Text style={styles.name}>
                            {products.item.name}
                        </Text>
                        <Text>
                        € {products.item.price}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.onPress(products.item)} > 
                            <Icon name="ios-add" color="white" size={25} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.onPress(products.item)} > 
                            <Icon name="ios-remove" color="white" size={25} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                    </View>
                </View>
            )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                style={styles.listContainer}
                data={this.state.filteredProducts}
                renderItem={this.renderProducts}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Products;
```

**reducers/cartItems**

```
const cartItems = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type)
    {
        case 'ADD_TO_CART':
            if (state.some(cartItem => cartItem.id === action.payload.id)) {
                // increase qty if item already exists in cart
                return state.map(cartItem => (
                    cartItem.id === action.payload.id ? { ...cartItem, qty: cartItem.qty + 1 } : cartItem

                    ));            
            }
            return [...state, { ...action.payload, qty: 1 }]; 
            // else add the new item to cart            
        case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':
            return state
                .map(cartItem => (cartItem.id === action.payload.id ? { ...cartItem, qty: cartItem.qty - 1 } : cartItem))
                .filter(cartItem => cartItem.qty > 0);
    }
    return state
} 
export default cartItems
```

**store/Index**

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import cartItems from '../reducers/carItems';

export default store = createStore(cartItems)
```

**App structure (simplified)**

```
Main folder
        ↳
          Containers(folder)
            ↳
             ProductsList.js
             CartList.js

          Components(folder)
            ↳
             Product.js
             cartProduct.js

          Reducers(folder)
            ↳
             carItems.js

          Actions(folder)
            ↳ 
             ProductActionCreators.js

          Navigation(folder)
            ↳
             AppNavigator,js
             MainTabNavigator.js

          Assets(folder for images etc.)
          Store(folder)
            ↳
             index.js
          App.JS
          Data.JS (using static JSON file for this development phase)
```

Comment: bindActionCreators is the most pointless function, just pass a plain key-value object and it will be wrapped in dispatch for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different actions, `addItemToCart`, `removeItem` which you define in mapDispatchToProps. Now that you specify a mapDispatchToProps argument to connect, the dispatch method is not available as a prop to the connected component, instead the method returns by mapDispatchToProps are only available

**Second,** you don't need to use `bindActionCreators` and definitely not in the component. `MapDispatchToProps` can simply be an object and connect will use dispatch internally.

**Third**, you need to pass the add and remove actions both to the child component.

**Fourth** you can pass multiple actions on to Product component simply as prop

Your code would look like

**ProductActionCreators.js**

```
export const ADD_TO_CART = 'ADD_TO_CART'
export const REMOVE_FROM_CART = 'REMOVE_FROM_CART'

export function addItemToCart(row) {
    return {
        type:'ADD_TO_CART', 
        payload: row
    }
  }

  export function removeItem(item) {
    return {
        type:'REMOVE_FROM_CART' , 
        payload: item
    }
  }
```

**ProductList**

```
  import React from 'react';
  import { Component } from 'react';
  import { 
    View,  
    StyleSheet, 
    Text
 } from 'react-native';
 import Products from '../components/Products';
 import { connect } from 'react-redux';

 import { addItemToCart, removeItem } from '../actions/ProductActionCreators';

 export  class ProductList extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null,
    };
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const { rows } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
        const arrays = Object.values( {rows});
        this.state = {
            arrays,
            filteredProducts: arrays,
        };
    }



      render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container} >
            <Text style={styles.title} >
                {this.state.arrays[0].name}
            </Text>
                <Products products={this.state.arrays[0].data} addItemToCart={this.props.addItemToCart} removeItem={this.props.removeItem}/>    
            </View>
        )
      }
    }


const mapDispatchToProps =  {
     addItemToCart,
     removeItem
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps) (ProductList);
```

**Product**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    TextInput,
    FlatList,
} from "react-native";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";

class Products extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const { products } = this.props;
        this.state = {
            products, 
            filteredProducts: products,
        };
    }
    renderProducts = (products) => {
            return (
                <View key={products.index}>
                    <View> 
                        <Icon name={products.item.icon} color="#DD016B" size={25} />
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <Text style={styles.name}>
                            {products.item.name}
                        </Text>
                        <Text>
                        € {products.item.price}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.addItemToCart(products.item)} > 
                            <Icon name="ios-add" color="white" size={25} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.removeItem(products.item)} > 
                            <Icon name="ios-remove" color="white" size={25} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                    </View>
                </View>
            )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                style={styles.listContainer}
                data={this.state.filteredProducts}
                renderItem={this.renderProducts}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Products;
```

Comment: Hi I accidently gave the points to someone else. Is there away I can correct this?

Comment: I don't think it can be undone. It gives you a warning popup on awarding bounty. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140290/bounty-awarded-to-a-different-answer-by-mistake

Comment: I'm terrible sorry. I was bit confused. :(

Comment: No problem, I am glad my answer was able to help you out :-)

Answer (score 1):

Code looks alright for most part.

The react-redux connect part in ProductList looks off. qty is always 0. It should be 1.

Also, mapStateToProps should be present to get the products from the cart.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The product QTY starts with 0 because of there being no product in the cart at the time. I thought, but I'll check it out tonight. Regarding the `mapStateToProps` could you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

In your `ProductList`, I'd approach the action binding like so:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
    return bindActionCreators({
        addItemToCart: (row, qty) => dispatch({
            type:'ADD_TO_CART', payload: {row, qty}
        }),
        removeItem: (product, qty) => dispatch({
            type:'REMOVE_FROM_CART' , payload: {product, qty}
        })  
    })
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductList);
```

Remove the action binding from your component's constructor as that's unnecessary.

You may want to split the code out into a `Container`/`Component`/ HOC approach, as I find it makes code far easier to read. As you've defined your actions in separate file, I'd also import these rather than redeclaring them.

If you follow this advice, you'd end up with the following:

**container.js**

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import ProductList from './product-list';

// Actions
import { addItemToCart, removeItem } from './actions';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {}
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        addItemToCart,
        removeItem,
    })
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductList);
```

**product-list.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import Products from '../components/Products';

export  class ProductList extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null,
    };
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const { rows } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
        const arrays = Object.values( {rows});
        this.state = {
            arrays,
            filteredProducts: arrays,
        };

        this.handleProductPress = this.handleProductPress.bind(this);
    }

    handleProductPress(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // This is pseudo code...
        this.props.addItemToCart(e.target.value, 1);
        return;
    } 

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container} >
                <Text style={styles.title} >
                    {this.state.arrays[0].name}
                </Text>
                <Products products={this.state.arrays[0].data} onPress={this.handleProductPress} />
           </View>
        ) 
    }
}

export default ProductList;
```

Have a play with that and see how you get on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll check it out tonight more thoroughly :)